# how to change positions in 2D array

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

For example, assuming that there are width and height, 6 and 4 respectively came from the user input and the inputs (also from the user inputs) that are stored in the 2D-array are:

```
0 1 2 2 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Is there any way to flip the x-axis and y-axis?
What I am trying to make is to change

```
0 1 2 2 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0
```

into

```
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1
2 0 0 1
2 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
```

The below code,

```
scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);
int board[height][width];

for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        board[i][j] = input;
    }
}
```

and by doing

```
for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
{

    for(j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", board[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

, this prints out the outputs that I expected, but it does not actually change its positions... I can`t change the first coding part since I already used it to do other works. Is there anyway to solve the problem by adding another methods or a new board?

Can someone please help me? I would be very thankful if someone helps me!
Thanks

Comment: You have to declare a second array and copy values from the first array to the second array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a second array with the specified number of rows equal to `width` and the number of columns equal to `height` and copy values from the souirce array to the second array.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t height, width;

    printf( "Enter the height and the width of the array: " );

    scanf( "%zu %zu", &height, &width );

    int a[height][width];

    puts( "Enter values for elements of the array" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu row: ", i + 1 );
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < width; j++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i][j] );
    }

    int b[width][height];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < width; j++ ) b[j][i] = a[i][j];
    }

    puts( "\nSource array is" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < width; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    puts( "\nReversed array is" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < width; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < height; j++ ) printf( "%d ", b[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the height and the width of the array: 4 6
Enter values for elements of the array
1 row: 0 1 2 2 1 0 
2 row: 1 0 0 0 0 1
3 row: 1 0 0 0 0 1 
4 row: 0 1 1 1 1 0 

Source array is
0 1 2 2 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1 1 0 

Reversed array is
0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 
2 0 0 1 
2 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 
0 1 1 0
```

Another approach is dynamically to allocate the first and the auxiliary arrays.
For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t height, width;

    printf( "Enter the height and the width of the array: " );

    scanf( "%zu %zu", &height, &width );

    int **a = malloc( height * sizeof( int * ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ ) a[i] = malloc( width * sizeof( int ) );

    puts( "Enter values for elements of the array" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu row: ", i + 1 );
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < width; j++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i][j] );
    }

    int **b = malloc( width * sizeof( int * ) );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < width; i++ ) b[i] = malloc( height * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < width; j++ ) b[j][i] = a[i][j];
    }

    puts( "\nSource array is" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < width; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < height; i++ ) free( a[i] );
    free( a );

    a = b;

    puts( "\nReversed array is" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < width; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < height; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < width; i++ ) free( a[i] );
    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest approach. Avoid copying and store the elements during the input. But if you cannot change the input procedure you have to copy elements using:

```
 void reverse_matrix(int c, int r, int board[][r], int board2[][c])
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int c, int r, int board[][r] )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void reverse_matrix(int c, int r, int board[][r], int board2[][c] )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            board2[j][i] = board[i][j];
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int width, height, input;

    scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);
    int board[height][width];

    int board2[width][height];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &input);
            board[i][j]  = input;
            // board2[j][i] = input; // if you can add it 
        }
    }

    printf("First matrix:\n");
    print(height, width, board);

    reverse_matrix(height, width, board, board2); // alternative

    printf("Second matrix:\n");
    print(width, height, board2);    

    return 0;    
}
```

Output:

```
2                                                                                                                                               
3                                                                                                                                               
1                                                                                                                                               
2                                                                                                                                               
3                                                                                                                                               
4                                                                                                                                               
5                                                                                                                                               
6                                                                                                                                               
First matrix:                                                                                                                                   
1 2                                                                                                                                             
3 4                                                                                                                                             
5 6                                                                                                                                             
Second matrix:                                                                                                                                  
1 3 5                                                                                                                                           
2 4 6
```